# overridding the base class virtual function in a custom derived class?

Tags: c++

I was trying to reuse the code of [riscv_fesvr](https://github.com/riscv-software-src/riscv-isa-sim/tree/master/fesvr).
Below is the code snippet I want your help with Below is a simplified version of the code.

Classes CM(chunked memif_t), M(memif), S(syscall_t) and H(htif_t) are part of the source code, what I want to do is to override the virtual functions defined in class M in a custom class Hc(htif_custom) which is not part of the source code, in such a way that when Class S uses the sys_write() it should use the write() definition defined in the Custom class and not the write() definition in Class M Below is the code and the problems I am facing while writing the code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CM{
    public:
      virtual void write_chunk()=0;
};

class M{
    public:
      M (CM* _c): c(_c) {}
      virtual void write(){
          cout<<"print from M write"<<endl;
          c->write_chunk();
      }
    protected:
      CM* c;
};

class H;
class M;

class S{
    public:
      S(H* _h) : h(_h), m(&_h.memif()) {}
      H* h;
      M* m;
      void sys_write(){
          m->write();
      }
};

class H : public CM{
    public:
      H(): m(this), s(this) {}
      virtual M& memif() {return m;}
      virtual void write_chunk()=0;
      M m;
      S s;
};


class Hc: public H, public M{
    public:
      Hc (): M(this) {}
      void write_chunk(){
          cout<<"print from Hc write_chunk"<<endl;
      }
      void write(){
          cout<<"print from Hc write"<<endl;
          write_chunk();
      }
      void print(){
          s.sys_write();
      }
};

int main(){
    Hc hc;
    hc.m.write();
    return 0;
}
```

the above code of Hc is my jab at overriding the write function if you have a better solution please mention that, my main aim is to override the class M write function so that I can replace the write definition with my custom definition. and whenever the source code tries to use the write function it should use my custom definition, without changing the source code.

Comment: What problems are you facing with regard to `M` exactly? The above example does not compile because `m(&_h.memif())` should be `m(_h->memif())` and you have to move the implementation to a point where `H` is defined.

Comment: Also, are you aware that `Hc` has two `CM` base classes? You might want to consider virtual inheritance.

Comment: not a problem but i want to override the definition of the class M definition of the write() function which is present in the riscv-fesvr source code such that whenever a class that is using the Class M write() function use my custom write() function given that write function is a virtual function in class M.
As for the error in the code snippet, it is just for show so that you don't have to go through all the riscv code. I have to correct the error you mention here but don't know how

Comment: You mean the error about incomplete types? Just move all implementations to .cpp files where you can include appropriate headers for all types. In the headers, you use forward declarations to break the cyclic dependencies.

Comment: let say i do think you mentioned, will that help me to override the defination of write function in the Class M.

Comment: No, that is totally unrelated, you still did not specify what problems are you having with the posted solution, does the override not work? It seems overriden to me. You should also use `override` keyword so you get better compiler diagnostics.

Comment: It's unclear what you're aksing/what your problem is. Please specify. Apart from the trivial error mentioned in Quimby's first comment, the code looks okay(ish) -- you should add `override` statements to help the compiler provide better diagnoistics.